# How to empty a continuously printing log file if size extends above a limit?

Tags: linux

I want empty a continuously printing log file in production,

**I use below command:**

```
echo > filename.log
```

I know the above command is used to empty continuously running log file if that file is getting too big.

- But my query is - What happens to the old file?Does that file gets backed up or the previous data is lost forever?
- How can I get the previous logs?

Comment: I think the topic you're looking for is 'log rotation' which basically governs when log files 'rotate', at which point a new log file is created and starts being filled up by your process.  This can be by time interval or size threshold. This might be a good place to start https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/how-do-i-rotate-log-files/

Answer (score 0):

Previous data is basically lost forever.

You can search for backup files.There can be a file named filename.log~ for filename.log in the same directory.

Answer (score 0):

It depends. If the other program has the log file permanently opened, the current log will be unlinked from its folder and your program just creates a brand new empty file. But the other program will still log to its now innaccessible file which will only be actually deleted when the program close it (or ends).

If the other program consistently uses the pattern open-write-close, you just erase previous content and new data will to that new file.

In any case old content is lost, but in first one the disk space is not reclaimed. If you want to keep it, you should google for *log rotate*